# Get Value from column depending on another column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
id               code                   text

100               1           short description 100
100               2             long descr 100
101               1           short description 101
```

Now I want to fetch data from `text` field depending on value in `code` field. if the code is `1` its short description and if code is `2` its long description.
My desire output is like this

```
id     shortdescription                    longdescription

100    short description 100               long descr 100
101    short description 101               null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,
          MAX(CASE WHEN code=1 THEN text END) as shortdescription,
          MAX(CASE WHEN code=2 THEN text END) as longdescription
   FROM TableName
GROUP BY id
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42181/1).

This query is same as:

```
SELECT id,MAX(shortdescription) as shortdescription,MAX(longdescription) as longdescription
FROM
(
   SELECT id,
          CASE WHEN code=1 THEN text END as shortdescription,
          CASE WHEN code=2 THEN text END as longdescription
   FROM TableName
) T
GROUP BY id
```

**NB:** To understand the working of this query, please execute the inner query first.

Result:

```
ID    SHORTDESCRIPTION        LONGDESCRIPTION
100   short description 100   long descr 100
101   short description 101   (null)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c947e/1).

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest approach is to treat this as conditional aggregation . . . put the `case` statement as an argument to the `max()` function:

```
select id,
       max(case when code = 1 then text end) as ShortDescription,
       max(case when code = 2 then text end) as LongDescription
from table t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two subqueries with the requested where condition (code = 1|2), then join them together (full outer join if any of them could missing).

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SHORTDESC.id, LONGDESC.id) AS id
    , SHORTDESC.[text] AS shortdesc
    , LONGDESC.[text] AS longdesc
FROM (
        SELECT
            id, [text]
        FROM
            yourTable
        WHERE
            code = 1
    ) SHORTDESC
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id, [text]
        FROM
            yourTable
        WHERE
            code = 2
    ) LONGDESC
        ON SHORTDESC.id = LONGDESC.id
```

Comment: Error: `The multi-part identifier "SORTDESC.id" could not be bound.` Change `SORTDESC` to `SHORTDESC` in `COALESCE`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've edited the answer. Thanks for the remark!